# Contact Forum from template not working

Tags: css, forms, web, dreamweaver

I have downloaded this fantastic web template called Brushed. It is heavy on css, which I am not too familiar with. I have managed to complete my personal webpage through trial and error, however, I am unable to get the CONTACT FORM to work through my servers.

The code from the template.

---

```
 <!-- Contact Form -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">

        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="mailto:info@elementsglobal.in">Submit</a>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What specifically is your problem? What would "work" be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a resource (e.g. uri) that you can post your form to on your server. That is, you need to change the following

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#">
```

to something like this

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="/contact/create">
```

And, you need to add a resource at "/contact/create" in your server that would parse form variables that are passed in from the post request, and do your thing (either save it to the database table or send yourself an email.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This resolved it. Also, the contact address on the php was incorrect. Cheers, McFee and Kim.

Answer (score 0):

The contact form wont work because you have the action set to # and you dont have a method of sending the data. So unless you are grabbing this data another way that you dont have posted you should start by fixing these

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="#"/*Fix this*/ method="post">
```